# Pivot Table in SQL Server returns null

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am using pivot query to get some data. Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
   Name, Institution, 
   [02 Jul 2015], [13 Jun 2015], [12 Jun 2015], 
   [10 Jun 2015], [09 Jun 2015]
FROM 
   [dbo].[mTable]
PIVOT(SUM(total) 
          FOR sDate IN ([02 Jul 2015], [13 Jun 2015], [12 Jun 2015],
                        [10 Jun 2015], [09 Jun 2015])) AS PivotTable
```

All data return correctly except for columns `[02 Jul 2015]`, `[13 Jun 2015]`, `[12 Jun 2015]` and `[10 Jun 2015]`, those are all returned as `null`.

Besides, there is a value in `mTable` for that `sDate`.

**OUTPUT** :

Name | Institution | [02 Jul 2015] | [13 Jun 2015] | [12 Jun 2015] | [10 Jun 2015] | [09 Jun 2015] 
A ------------ 1 ---------- NULL ---------- NULL ------------ NULL ----------- NULL ----------- 500

Please help me.

Comment: Hi Margaretha, edit your question and add a minimal set of data for `mTable` that highlights the problem.

Comment: Does your data contain these days: [02 Jul 2015], [13 Jun 2015], [12 Jun 2015] and [10 Jun 2015]? Is your `sdate` column `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: `datetime` but it was converted to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Tanggal, 106)`